# How to copy a file over a socket in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sockets

I'm trying to copy a file over a socket. This works. However, the script never ends. I get stuck in an endless while loop reading data over the socket. Thank you so much in advance.

```
server = TCPServer.new 5555

Thread.new do
  client = server.accept

  file = File.new('files.zip', 'rb')

  while line = file.read(1024)
    client.write line
  end
end

socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
file = File.new('files_backup.zip', 'wb')
while line = socket.read(1024)
  file.write line
end
```

I tried with nil as well.

```rb
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 5555

Thread.new do
  client = server.accept
  client.write File.binread 'files.zip'
  client.write nil
end

socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
file = File.new('files_backup.zip', 'wb')

while line = socket.read(1024)
  unless line
    break
  end
  file.write line
end

file.close
```

Updated with the length as the size of the read.

```rb
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 5555

Thread.new do
  client = server.accept
  content = File.binread('hackers.zip')
  client.write content.length
  client.write content
end

socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
file = File.new('hackers_backup.zip', 'wb')

length = socket.gets.to_i
content = socket.read length
file.write content
file.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never tell the script to stop reading. The `read(1024)` function is blocking and it never returns nil while the socket is open. Easiest fix would be to close the socket when the file is sent. You should also close the file to write the data when you don't expect more.

```rb
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 5555

Thread.new do
  client = server.accept
  file = File.new('files.zip', 'rb')
  while line = file.read(1024)
    client.write line
  end
  client.close
end

socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
file = File.new('files_backup.zip', 'wb')
while line = socket.read(1024)
  file.write line
end
file.close
```

If you want to keep the connection you have to come with some kind of a protocol. Maybe start a communication with a line saying the file length. Then you can read the first line and later read the expected number of bytes from the socket.

```rb
require 'socket'
server = TCPServer.new 5555

Thread.new do
  client = server.accept
  file = File.new('files.zip', 'rb')
  client.puts file.size
  while line = file.read(1024)
    client.write line
  end
end

socket = TCPSocket.new('localhost', 5555)
length = socket.gets.to_i
File.open('files_backup.zip', 'wb'){|f| f.write(socket.read(length)) }
```

Bonus point would be sending a checksum in the header and validating the file upon receive.

Comment: See . That's where I'm stuck. I can't close the connection. I understand what you're saying though.

Comment: I tried with nil

Comment: @ChrisBasinger I have updated the answer with example code for the file transfer with the file length sent before the file data.

Comment: I tried your solution and it didn't work. you can see my code.

Comment: @ChrisBasinger `socket.write` wouldn't add a newline at the end. Use `socket.puts`